# Integrating external web server in IIS website

Tags: iis, iis-7, reverse-proxy

I have a problem with configuring IIS inorder of integrating an external web service into the current web interface provided by IIS.

The normal site is located in the base URL like this:

http://localhost/

The external service is located on the same machine, but on a different port (3030). I would however be able to reach this from the following URL:

http://localhost/external_service/

Is there a way to configure IIS to call the external server on behalf of the web browser and return the result to the web browser ?

Answer (score 0):

If your service is on a different port then your access to it will be http://localhost:3030/external_service unless you setup a DNS entry and/or host file entry pointing it to http://localhost:3030 for you.

As far as having IIS call it you could do it with a redirect to the service.  However, displaying results of calling something in the service will require a consumer of the service. AKA - a web application not just IIS by itself.

Comment: No, the external web service cannot be reached from the outside and the firewall cannot be opened, so IIS have to act as some sort of proxy.